# Number of pairwise overlapping balls in n dimensions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am looking for a closed form formula for the maximum number of balls in $n$ dimensions with the following conditions:

- All balls must have a non-empty pairwise intersection
- There must be no point inside more than 2 balls (i.e., no 3 way intersection)

In 1D, we do not really have balls, but we could think of the intersection as the region between G and F, so we have at most 2 balls [image: In 1D, the intersection is a segment]

In 2D, we have the following, I do not see a way to have more than 4 balls [image: In 2D, we can draw 4 balls following the conditions]

In 3D, it is possible to fit 5 balls, like this [image: 3D image showing 4 balls following the conditions, the 5th one which could be placed in front is left out so the 4 would remain visible.]
So, the question is 1. whether these numbers are correct for 1-3 dimensions and whether there is a general formula to compute the maximum number of balls.

Comment: in the 2d picture, you see there is a region bounded by the three circles, draw a little circle centred at its centre and going slightly beyond it

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: In the $\Bbb{R}^3$ picture, the balls at $B$ and $E$ seem to not intersect (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @TheoBendit you're right. I updated that picture as well now.

Comment: I am more and more convinced that this problem is a lot harder than it seems. i was looking into sphere/circle packing, contact graphs and kissing numbers and it appears that there are some results for balls in three dimensions, but not always for higher dimensions. Most of these works look at unit-spheres, though.